# C++ class method that take instance of the same class

Tags: c++, c++11

Im new to c++, I'm trying to have a class that has a method that take an instance of it self. Here what I'm try to achieve.

```
Class A {

public:

std::vector<int>* getData(){return &data;}

// I need to merge the data from 2 class, so in my code 
//I can call p.merge(c) where p&c instance of A

void Merge (A* ptr) {
   data = ptr->getData()->data;
}

private:

std::vector<int> data;

}
```

Any idea how to do the merge function.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a method take an instance of its own class - or are you asking how to write a merge function?

Comment: If you want a pointer to `A`, declare `(A * ptr)`; if you want a copy declare `(A a)`; if you want a reference `(A & a)` (or `(A const & a)` for a reference to an `A` const value). But if you receive a copy or a reference, you have to call `getData()` using a `.`, not a `->`.

Comment: so if i use void Merge (A* ptr) how do I copy the vector? data = ptr->getDtat()->data; is not working ?

Comment: `data += ptr->data;`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ptr->getData()->data;
```

In the above line, `data` is a `std::vector<int>`. The return value of `ptr->getData()` is a `std::vector<int> *`.

The latter does not have a member named `data`.

So you probably want to replace that line with

```
data = *ptr->getData();
```

or

```
data = ptr->data;
```

Also note that if you want the data to be merged rather than replaced, you want to use a different method:

```
data.insert(data.end(), ptr->data.begin(), ptr->data.end());
```